# Recover permutation of a vector

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, permutation

In numpy, how do I efficiently recover the permutation applied by a sorting algorithm to a vector such that at at every index in the resulting vector I have an integer representing the index the item in the orginal vector gets projected to after the application of the sorting algorithm.

```py
>>>import numpy as np

>>> my_vector = np.random.random_integers(1,50,size=5)
>>> my_vector
array([23, 20, 33, 38, 27])

>>> my_v_sorted = np.sort(my_vector)
>>> my_v_sorted
array([20, 23, 27, 33, 38])

>>> what_i_want = np.array([1,0,4,2,3])
```

I want regardless of whether I actually need to sort to do this, I just want to mapping of the entries of my vector to the resulting indexes in the sorted vector, cheers!

Comment: Have you looked at [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)?

Comment: `what_i_want = np.array([1,0,4,5,3])` Should there be a `2` in there? And no `5`?

Comment: Look at the argsort of the argsort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.argsort()`

```
import numpy as np

my_vector = np.array([23, 20, 33, 38, 27])

my_v_sorted = np.sort(my_vector)

what_i_want = np.argsort(my_vector)
```

This gives you the following output

```
>>> my_v_sorted
>>> array([20, 23, 27, 33, 38])

>>> what_i_want
>>> array([1, 0, 4, 2, 3])
```